# Call to a member function links() on array in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I dont know what happens. I am using pagination but it gives me error
like:- Call to a member function links() on array

Here is My code 
Function:-

```
enter code here


use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;
    public function index(){
       $data =  DB::table('tasks')->paginate(1);
        $data= json_decode(json_encode($data),true); 
        return view('index',['data'=>$data]);
    }
```

And i used in blade file in end where foreach finish:-

```
enter code here
{{ $data->links() }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont have to decode the json. Read the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/pagination

You should do this:

```
public function index(){
   $data =  DB::table('tasks')->paginate(1);

   return view('index',['data'=>$data]);
}
```